# How to convert on DECIMALS on UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, casting, sql-update

I Have this table (runner_orders):
[image: table]

Columns `distance` and `duration` contain data written differently (20, 20km, null). I want to convert them all in DECIMALS (from Varchar).

I tried with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(distance AS DECIMAL) AS distance_in_km,
    CAST(duration AS DECIMAL) AS duration_in_minutes
FROM runner_orders;
```

And it works. Here the result:

[image: result]

However, if I then try to apply the same query in an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE runner_orders
SET distance = CAST(distance AS DECIMAL);
```

I get this error:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '20km'

Why can't I convert on UPDATE?

Comment: Annoyingly mysql is much tougher on validation in updates than selects - use replace to lose km and add decimal size and precision.

Comment: *And it works* - does it? You have lost your decimal places without specifying the scale.

Comment: @Stu thanks for your reply, I was focused on the UPDATE and I didn't pay much attention to the decimal numbers, I changed the query so now I also have the numbers after the separator.

Comment: you must change the column to VARCHAR type or leave only the numbers and then in the query make a concat of the distance and by KMS.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't convert it to decimal in the update statement because `distance` row has varchar type. You should ALTER if firstly to Decimal to get desire result

Comment: Hi, I tried with ALTER but I get the same error.  `ALTER TABLE runner_orders
MODIFY COLUMN distance DECIMAL;`

Comment: if you mean alter table table modify column distance decimal(10,2); then the same error will occur.